# Выключение программы в PyCharm

Tags: бот, pycharm, discord.py

Написал бота Discord, запустил его, лег спать, проснулся, и увидел что Windows обновился и закрыл PyCharm, но бот остался в сети и хорошо работал, я пытался его выключить, но успехов нет.

Comment: Через диспетчер задач смотрел, есть ли процесс python?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте в коде функцию `exit()`

Пример:

```
for val in range(0,5):
    if val == 3:
        print(exit)
        exit()
    print(val)
```

Или тому подобные. [Подробнее..](https://pythonguides.com/python-exit-command/)

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы, после закрытия PyCharm все потоки, которые запускались через него умирают. Возможно, что у вас где-то висит процесс PyCharm либо Python с вашим ботом. Можете попробовать создать скрипт и написать туда этот код, чтобы убить все процессы, кроме текущего

```
import re, datetime, psutil, os
print('current process: '+str(os.getpid()))
for process in psutil.process_iter():
    if str(process.pid) == str(os.getpid()):
        current_started = re.findall(r'\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}', str(process))[0]

for process in psutil.process_iter():
    if "python.exe" in str(process.name):
        if str(process.pid) != str(os.getpid()):
            if str(current_started)!= re.findall(r'\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}', str(process))[0]:
                os.system("Taskkill /PID "+str(process.pid)+"")
```

Код взял [отсюда](https://coderoad.ru/32713131/%D0%A3%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-python-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE)